# In C language how to find array size in user defined function with that array being passed from main()

Tags: c, arrays

I have declared an array in main() and to find the size of an array I can use sizeof() and this gives me the correct result. When the same array is passed to another user defined function and if I use sizeof() then I am not getting expected results.
In the code I have attached, I get size of array as 10 in main() but in user defined function, I am getting array size as 2. 
My question is why its not showing 10? Or is there any other solution for this?

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int array(int a[])
  {
   int x=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
   printf("\n in user defined() size is %d",x);
   }
  int main()
  {   int a[10],i,x;
      for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      a[i]=i+1;

      x=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
      printf("\n in main() size is %d",x);
      array(a);

      return 0;
  }


  output:
 in main() size is 10
 in user defined() size is 2
```

Comment: No way. The array is decaying to a pointer. Pass the size along.

Comment: There no such language as "C/C++". Please stop using that phrase.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am afraid that term will never die.